# center text in SVG circle

Tags: html, css, svg

I have checked different solutions provided here in StackOverflow for a problem like this to no avail. For the life of me I do not know what's not working.

You may be wondering "why use a SVG". I have to create a circle in HTML and position it over a banner, it's for a client. I have found that creating a SVG shape is the best way I have to create such circle. This is my current SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="#472e12" />
    <foreignobject x="20" y="20" width="20" height="20">
    <style>
        p   { text-anchor:middle;}
    </style>
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <div>
        <p>Text in two lines</p>
    </div>
    </body>
</foreignobject>
    </svg>
```

And here's the CSS for it:

```
 svg{
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        bottom: 40px;
    }
```

It is a small brown circle and it should have a text in two lines, centered, in white.

Comment: Do you need more than 2 lines?

Comment: No, just two. I should have a word in the first line and another word in the second line, both centered.

Comment: let me see that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your text span multiple lines, you'll need to make use of `<tspan>`. To make the text white, you'll need to give it a `stroke` or `fill` of `#fff`. I've gone with `fill` to make it sharper. As for the text itself, you may find it easier to just use `<text>`, and do something similar to the following:

```html
<svg width="200" height="100">
  <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="#472e12" />
  <text x="50%" y="30%" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" dy=".3em">
    <tspan x="20%" dy=".6em">Text In</tspan>
    <tspan x="20%" dy="1.2em">Two Lines</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Good one. You may want to use `fill="#fff"` rather than stroke, to have the text more sharp...

Comment: Updated to use `fill` instead :)

Comment: omg this worked like a charm! thank you so so much. The question I have is: why 30% instead of 50% in the Y axis - which I think would be the most logical thing I guess?

Comment: Because you have two lines of text. I **could** have used 50%, but that would have made the first line exactly in the middle, and second line quite low down. I shifted it up to display both lines slightly more attractively, though feel free to adjust to suit :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge what if you had multiple circles and wanted to center text in each? Do I need an extra `<svg>` element?

```<svg width="200" height="100">
  <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="#472e12" />
  <circle cx="120" cy="40" r="40" fill="#472e12" />
  <text x="50%" y="30%" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" dy=".3em">
  </text>
  // how to add centered text to the second circle?
</svg>```

Answer (score 2):

Here the `y` position of `text` strongly depends on the `font-size` attribute.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="#472e12" />
    <text x="40" y="40" fill="#FFF" font-size="20px" text-anchor="middle"  >
      1 line
    </text>
    <text x="40" y="60" fill="#FFF" font-size="20px" text-anchor="middle">
      2 line
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: This worked too! Thank you man. I think the foreignObject killed me haha

Comment: No problem as long as it helped you I'm happy